# AsyncResponse and Java 8 parallel stream issue

Tags: rest, parallel-processing, java-8, jersey

I am using spring boot with `Jersey rest api`

```
@POST
@Path("test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void test(final List<String> requests, @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {

    List<String> resplist = new ArrayList();
    requests.parallelStream().forEach(req -> {

        String resp = //some process to get (Always return string)
        resplist.add(resp);
    });

    asyncResponse.resume(resplist);

}
```

If I use `parallelStream` sometimes the list that is retrieved on the client side does not return all the elements.

Lets say I pass 30 it returns 29 but sometime it does return 30 (Request is always the same)

But If I use normal stream with **`forEach`** only, then it always returns me 30 elements.

Is this some sort of bug? Can I not use parallelStream in rest api

**UPDATE**

As answered by Eugene this was the issue because when using parallel stream multiple threads were adding record into arraylist which is not threadsafe

**solution** 
Use Synch collection

```
Collection<String> resplist = Collections.synchronizedCollection(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see you are relying on side-effects here in the part:

```
.forEach(req -> {

            String resp = //some process to get (Always return string)
           resplist.add(resp);
             });
```

You are spawning multiple threads to add elements to a non-thread-safe collection such as `ArrayList`.

You should instead collect those via `.collect(Collectors.toList())`