# No thread-bound request error in parallel stream in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an endpoint on my controller which takes a list of IDs. For each ID I fetch details from a REST endpoint which I would like to do asynchronously. This is my implementation:

```
@PostMapping("/leaderboard")
@ApiOperation("Get clients leaderboard statistics")
public List<Dto> clientLeaderboard(@RequestBody List<String> accountIds) {

    IntStream.range(0, accountIds.size()).parallel().forEach(i -> {
        AccountDTO accountDTO = accountMaintenanceRestClient.getAccount(accountIds.get(i));
        // More logic
    }

}
```

This then gives me the error:

> Unhandled exception occurred
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

I've actually experienced this error before and managed to fix it in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526553/multithreading-within-spring-controller-no-thread-bound-request-found/57311108#57311108). Is the same solution applicable here? If so how can I provide my existing executor to this parallel stream?

*Edit*

AccountMaintenanceRestClient code. I'm using [OpenFeign](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign) as part of this.

```
public interface AccountMaintenanceRestClient {
   @RequestLine("GET /account/{accountId}")
   @Profiled(tag = "AccountMaintenanceRestClient.{$0}.getAccountBalance", logFailuresSeparately = true)
   AccountDTO getAccount(@Param("accountId") String accountId);

   @RequestLine("GET /referencedata/statuscode")
   @Profiled(tag = "AccountMaintenanceRestClient.getStatusCodes", logFailuresSeparately = true)
   Map<String, String> getStatusCodes();

   @RequestLine("GET /referencedata/websites")
   @Profiled(tag = "AccountMaintenanceRestClient.getWebsitesIds", logFailuresSeparately = true)
   List<WebSiteDTO> getWebsitesIds();
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:735)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:160)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfInt.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:189)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline.forEach(IntPipeline.java:404)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline$Head.forEach(IntPipeline.java:560)
    at com.foobar.wt.igip.gateway.web.controllers.surge.paris.SurgeParisController.clientLeaderboard(SurgeParisController.java:58)
    at com.foobar.wt.igip.gateway.web.controllers.surge.paris.SurgeParisController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a143909.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:667)
    at com.foobar.wt.igip.gateway.web.controllers.surge.paris.SurgeParisController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$67cb3a1e.clientLeaderboard(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:854)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:765)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at uk.co.igindex.commons.bluegreen.IGClusterDetailsFilter.doFilter(IGClusterDetailsFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1757)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1716)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.currentRequestAttributes(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.access$400(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AutowireUtils$ObjectFactoryDelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(AutowireUtils.java:307)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getHeader(Unknown Source)
    at com.foobar.wt.igip.gateway.support.FeignSSOTokenRequestInterceptor.apply(FeignSSOTokenRequestInterceptor.java:22)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.targetRequest(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:158)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:88)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156.getAccount(Unknown Source)
    at com.foobar.wt.igip.gateway.web.controllers.surge.paris.SurgeParisController.lambda$clientLeaderboard$2(SurgeParisController.java:59)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfInt.accept(ForEachOps.java:205)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:110)
    at java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:693)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

FeignSSOTokenRequestInterceptor:

```
import feign.RequestInterceptor;
import feign.RequestTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Component
public class FeignSSOTokenRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
   private static final String SSO_HEADER_NAME = "X-SECURITY-TOKEN";
   private final HttpServletRequest request;

   @Autowired
   public FeignSSOTokenRequestInterceptor(HttpServletRequest request) {
      this.request = request;
   }

   @Override
   public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
      requestTemplate.header(SSO_HEADER_NAME, request.getHeader(SSO_HEADER_NAME));
   }
}
```

Comment: I think this bean `accountMaintenanceRestClient` must be `request` or `session` scoped

Comment: share the code for accountMaintenanceRestClient and how you are using.

Comment: @Deadpool yeah, looks like it is being handled/called/autowired a `top level component` on thread-bound request which should not be handled.

Comment: Added the rest client code.

Comment: @Nanor could you post `entire stacktrace` of error?

Comment: @JonathanJohx Added stacktrace

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `AysncResponse`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630802/asyncresponse-and-java-8-parallel-stream-issue, https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/rest/enableasync-async-controller/ ?

Comment: You have a mix of sync ( the controller itself ) and async functions. The async will be pushed at the back -to run as async, nothing strange- and the controller will be left without an answer trying to move on synchronously.. Maybe try to bind it in the same context. Something like the `AsyncResponse` that was suggested or ( wild guess ) a `.map()` to attach the session in sequence of the async task

Comment: Show the code of `FeignSSOTokenRequestInterceptor` please

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FeignSSOTokenRequestInterceptor` depends on `HttpServletRequest` proxied bean.

The request is exposed via threadlocal so threads in threadpool has no knowledge/aware of it, hence exception occurs when it try to read the request from threadlocal map.

So basically the problem narrowed down to how to set the request to the threadpool's thread context.

Setup a threadpool like your referenced post then submit the task,

```
@Autowired
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor poolExecutor;

CountdownLatch counter = new CountdownLatch(accountIds.size());
IntStream.range(0, accountIds.size()) // Note that .parallel is omitted
         .forEach(() -> poolExecutor.submit(() -> {
             try {
                your task
             } finally {
                counter.countDown();
             }
         })) 
counter.await(); // Wait for all tasks complete
```

This is prefered way, because the default parallel stream is used a common shared pool, you should not place a task has heavy IO like API access to that)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to throw some light on the question.

FeignSSOTokenRequestInterceptor is your custom RequestInterceptor and you are trying to access ServletRequest inside the apply method which is evident from the stack trace

**RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:320)**

This RequestObjectFactory is a static inner class which gives you access the current request

```
private static class RequestObjectFactory implements ObjectFactory<ServletRequest>, Serializable {
    private RequestObjectFactory() {
    }

    public ServletRequest getObject() {
        return WebApplicationContextUtils.currentRequestAttributes().getRequest();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Current HttpServletRequest";
    }
}
```

the current request is derived from the RequestContextHolder class which gets the attribute from the current thread as shown below after a series of method calls

```
 //This is the current thread which holds the request attributes
    private static final ThreadLocal<RequestAttributes> requestAttributesHolder = new NamedThreadLocal("Request attributes");

     //This is the place where you get the actual exception from the spring RequestContextHolder class.
     public static RequestAttributes currentRequestAttributes() throws IllegalStateException {
        RequestAttributes attributes = getRequestAttributes();
        if (attributes == null) {
            if (jsfPresent) {
                attributes = RequestContextHolder.FacesRequestAttributesFactory.getFacesRequestAttributes();
            }

            if (attributes == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.");
            }
        }

        return attributes;
    }

     public static RequestAttributes getRequestAttributes() {
            RequestAttributes attributes = (RequestAttributes)requestAttributesHolder.get();
            if (attributes == null) {
                attributes = (RequestAttributes)inheritableRequestAttributesHolder.get();
            }

            return attributes;
        }
```

**final verdict:** 
so make sure you are not trying to access the ServletRequest from the RequestInterceptor if you are using parallel streams. since parallel streams must be used only with **stateless, non-interfering, and associative operations**

**since requestAttributesHolder.get() looks for the current thread do not use parallel streams on it** as shown below .which is not recommended and parallelism has a lot of things to be considered refer([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html))

```
public T get() {
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    ThreadLocalMap map = getMap(t);
    if (map != null) {
        ThreadLocalMap.Entry e = map.getEntry(this);
        if (e != null) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T result = (T)e.value;
            return result;
        }
    }
    return setInitialValue();
}
```

if you do not have any code that is accessing the current request and it's being called from the **OpenFeign**  class files then the only way is to use the sequential streams instead of parallel streams.which is straightforward

```
accountIds.stream().forEach(accountId -> {
    AccountDTO accountDTO = accountMaintenanceRestClient.getAccount(accountId);
    // More logic
}
```